# OnClick on a dynamically created listbox

Tags: java, android, json, listbox, onclick

I've a problem, I followed some tutorial and I finally managed how to create a dinamical ListBox but I have a problem, I don't know how to set the OnClick on the items created dinamically, here is my snippet:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, serverList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();



    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest serverReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            server elemento = new server();
                            elemento.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            elemento.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            elemento.setStatus(obj.getString("status"));
                            elemento.setIp(obj.getString("ip"));

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            serverList.add(elemento);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(serverReq);
}
```

and this is my list adapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<server> serverItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<server> serverItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.serverItems = serverItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return serverItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return serverItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        TextView ip = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ip);
        TextView status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

        // getting data for the row
        server m = serverItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // ip
        ip.setText("Ip: " + String.valueOf(m.getIp()));



        // status
        status.setText(String.valueOf(m.getStatus()));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I don't really know where and how to add the OnClick event of every item of the listbox, because it should be made with dynamical info took from the data took by the json adapter, can someone help me?
Thanks, Matteo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right, you don't need to add `setOnClickListener` to each of item.

Use `listview.setOnItemClickListener` it will handle click for each & every element

Add it below

> listview.setAdapter()

Here is a sample :

```
listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) 
{
/   /here you have the position so you can do whatever you want with this item


 }
 });
```